# Saving certificate acceptance with Java Web Start in Windows 7?

Tags: java, windows-7, certificate, jnlp, java-web-start

I deploy a java application with Java Web Start (JWS) from an online server. The JNLP file contains the security `all-permissions` tag and I signed the application with my own certificate.

For some users (Windows7+Java7) Java Virtual Machine (JVM) asks to accept the unknown certificate every time they launch the application, in spite of checking the box `always trust this unknown editor`.

In normal, the JVM asks to accept the unknown certificate only once, until its expiration.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: *"In normal, the JVM asks to accept the unknown certificate only once, until its expiration."*  That is ***abnormal*** for a self-signed certificate.  My experience has long been that unsigned certificates cause the JRE to 'forget' the 'always remember' - the moment after it is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I realized that Java 7 doesn't work as Java 6. The option "always trust this unknown certificate" is hidden in the "display options" panel. I just forgot to open my eyes...